# Why imported textures from Substance Painter looks wrong in Blender?

Tags: texturing, import, pbr

I baked high poly meshes' details into low poly meshes and textured them in Adobe Substance Painter. When I import the textures back to Blender, it looks different. It seems that the problem comes from the metallic map. How do I fix this?

[Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c2nBVA-86z1hZThyYvmk09LvxIUR4T6f/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I took a second look at your normal map texture which was disconnected in your file and it seems that your bake has gone wrong. We can see the ugly geometry around the key's hole. I don't think that's how it was supposed to look.

[image: normal map]

Aside from that, ticking [x] Auto Smooth still stands.

Comment: Shouldn't the smoothness come from the high poly mesh? Also, it doesn't fix the problem.
https://prnt.sc/CPtksXR-w0da

Comment: @melly_berk Edited my answer above. As for that smooth key part, you can turn down autosmooth to like 18° or something and the edges should become visible.

Comment: @melly_berk I just imported the low poly into Sbs Painter and put your normal map on it and it looks like it has the same issue as blender. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Well, from all those tutorials that I watched online, I thought you were supposed to not use auto smooth for the low poly because the smoothness should be baked from the high poly, it's just not the case it seems, auto smooth seems the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @melly_berk those tutorials could be right. Anyway don't give up on baking normals, autosmooth is just a band aid on your problem. Maybe you need to tweak some baking settings. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: @melly_berk no those tutorials are wrong, or you might be confusing AutoSmooth with SubDivision Modifiers. Autosmooth is meant to be used to preserve clean normals in the low poly by splitting the vertex normals where the angle exceeds a certain threshhold.. The problem in your mesh is actually coming from relying too MUCH on the high poly to smooth the normals. Make sure your low poly at least has smooth edges on the uv seams, if not more where they might be needed (usually a setting between 30 and 45 degrees works fine) and your bakes should come out looking alright.

Comment: @Jakemoyo I'm still having problems with baking normal maps. This guy-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W7txa9ltBw and this guy -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpx4QxuetNs didn't use auto smooth. They also didn't export painter textures back to the Blender, (I assume if they did, they would have the same problem that I did). I'm just lost.

Comment: Okay, the first video doesn't set auto smooth because his mesh is so simple that shade flat is the same as AS. The second video belongs in the garbage, that guy has no idea what he's doing. Take your mesh, shade smooth, then enable auto smooth and set the degree to like 45. Then go into edit mode, run Select all Sharp edges to set all edges at 45 degrees to be seams. It's important that the sharp edges in auto smooth also have UV seams or you'll get bake errors. Then unwrap it with those seams. Then bake it. That should do the trick.

Comment: Read these posts [1](https://polycount.com/discussion/81154/understanding-averaged-normals-and-ray-projection-who-put-waviness-in-my-normal-map) [2](https://polycount.com/discussion/107196/making-sense-of-hard-edges-uvs-normal-maps-and-vertex-counts) as many times as it takes to internalize the info.

Comment: @Jakemoyo You're a diamond mate! Thanks for the help.